# How to merge 2 ArrayLists of LinkedHashMaps using groovy

Tags: groovy

Need some help merging 2 ArrayLists of LinkedHashMaps based on a couple keys.

Here's what the data looks like:

```
​def searchResults = [ 
  [dId:"prod_000001", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName:"Subject 1", dTitle:"Title 1"],
  [dId:"prod_000002", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName:"Subject 1", dTitle:"Title 2"],
  [dId:"prod_000003", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName:"Subject 2", dTitle:"Title 3"],
  [dId:"prod_000004", groupName:"Group 2", subjectName:"Subject 1", dTitle:"Title 4"]
]

def groupInfo = [ 
  [groupName:"Group 1", groupId:"01", subjectName:"Subject 1", subjectSortOrder:"01"],
  [groupName:"Group 1", groupId:"01", subjectName:"Subject 2", subjectSortOrder:"02"],
  [groupName:"Group 1", groupId:"01", subjectName:"Subject 3", subjectSortOrder:"03"],
  [groupName:"Group 2", groupId:"02", subjectName:"Subject 1", subjectSortOrder:"01"] 
]
```

I need to merge the attributes from groupInfo with searchResults based on groupName and subjectName, something like:

```
def mergedResults = mergeResults(searchResults,groupInfo,["groupName","subjectName"])
```

Which would result in:

```
mergedResult = [
  [dId:"prod_000001", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName: "Subject 1", dTitle: "Title 1", groupID:"01", subjectSortOrder:"01"],
  [dId:"prod_000002", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName: "Subject 1", dTitle: "Title 2", groupID:"01", subjectSortOrder:"01"],
  [dId:"prod_000003", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName: "Subject 2", dTitle: "Title 3", groupID:"01", subjectSortOrder:"02"],
  [dId:"prod_000004", groupName:"Group 2", subjectName: "Subject 1", dTitle: "Title 4", groupID:"02", subjectSortOrder:"01"]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line does that:

```
def mergedResults = searchResults.collect { searchResult ->
    searchResult + groupInfo.find {
        it.groupName == searchResult.groupName &&
        it.subjectName == searchResult.subjectName
    }
}
```

And here a second alternative:

```
def mergedResults = [searchResults, groupInfo]
    .combinations()
    .findAll {
        x, y -> x.groupName == y.groupName &&
                x.subjectName == y.subjectName
    }
    .collect { it.sum() }
```

And a third variant with building a lookup map:

```
def keyFn = { it.subMap 'groupName', 'subjectName' } 
groupInfo = groupInfo.collectEntries { [keyFn(it), it] }
def mergedResults = searchResults.collect { it + (groupInfo[keyFn(it)] ?: [:]) }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a faster lookup, I'd `groupBy` the `groupInfo` on a
`subMap(["groupName", "subjectName"])` first.  Then iterate the `searchResults`,
see if there is an entry in `groupInfo` and merge them all in.

```
def keyFn = { it.subMap(["groupName", "subjectName"]) } 

def searchResults = [ 
    [dId:"prod_000001", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName:"Subject 1", dTitle:"Title 1"],
    [dId:"prod_000002", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName:"Subject 1", dTitle:"Title 2"],
    [dId:"prod_000003", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName:"Subject 2", dTitle:"Title 3"],
    [dId:"prod_000004", groupName:"Group 2", subjectName:"Subject 1", dTitle:"Title 4"]
]

def groupInfo = [ 
    [groupName:"Group 1", groupId:"01", subjectName:"Subject 1", subjectSortOrder:"01"],
    [groupName:"Group 1", groupId:"01", subjectName:"Subject 2", subjectSortOrder:"02"],
    [groupName:"Group 1", groupId:"01", subjectName:"Subject 3", subjectSortOrder:"03"],
    [groupName:"Group 2", groupId:"02", subjectName:"Subject 1", subjectSortOrder:"01"] 
].groupBy(keyFn) // XXX note the groupBy

// merge all search results by groupname/subjectName keys into each searchResult
def mergedResult = searchResults.collect{
    (groupInfo[keyFn(it)]?:[]).inject(it){ a,b -> a+b }
}

assert mergedResult == [
    [dId:"prod_000001", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName: "Subject 1", dTitle: "Title 1", groupId:"01", subjectSortOrder:"01"],
    [dId:"prod_000002", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName: "Subject 1", dTitle: "Title 2", groupId:"01", subjectSortOrder:"01"],
    [dId:"prod_000003", groupName:"Group 1", subjectName: "Subject 2", dTitle: "Title 3", groupId:"01", subjectSortOrder:"02"],
    [dId:"prod_000004", groupName:"Group 2", subjectName: "Subject 1", dTitle: "Title 4", groupId:"02", subjectSortOrder:"01"]
]
```